# create-react-app - Why localhost is not working?

Tags: reactjs

After creating a new react app using create-react-app, once I start the dev server via **npm start**, the server started and shows this:

[image]

I'm sure that until last week I could open http://localhost:3000 to see the new created app in browser, but now it doesn't work any more and shows this:

[image]

But, it works if I open http://192.168.119:3000

I haven't changed anything inside my .hosts file.

Does any one know why I cannot use http://localhost:3000 any more?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned nothing is changed inside the .hosts file.

Comment: Are you sure you're it's http:// and not http**s**:// you're trying to open? See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40430501/127-0-0-1-this-site-can-t-provide-a-secure-connection

Comment: Have you used an agent?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your help guys.
After emptying the browser cache and flushing the DNS it's now working again.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and checked that my VPN ( I use warp) is turned off already. However, when I turned it on, my local worked again.

Comment: The exact same thing worked for me. Any idea why you need to turn on Warp? Doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I did not delve into it to be honest. But after VPN-on launch, even after turning the VPN off  did not create any sort of blockage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used an agent?

ping localhost, check it is 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Little late to this, but i came across the same issue; Turned out my vpn app was running preventing me from accessing the app on http://localhost:3000.
So, turning off the vpn should resolve the issue